# (US) Under what circumstances can a person be forced to enter a facility for having a mental illness?

Tags: united-states, mental-health

Though this question would be great to know for various legal systems, I'm tagging this with [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) since it will likely be complicated enough with just a single country being considered.

When can someone be legally required to enter a facility because of their mental illness? Are there particular diagnoses that would be enough? Would they have to commit a crime first? Could a doctor require it of them?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5150_(involuntary_psychiatric_hold)) and related legislation may be interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary reason for involuntary commitment is that a person poses **a threat to themselves or others**.

This is usually intentionally broad, but can be taken to mean suicidal, delusional or homicidal tendencies, or other personality disorders that make a person a threat.

There are usually provisions for holding a person for a limited period of time in emergency situations - for example, if they have recently attempted to commit suicide.

Each State will have different standards required to have a person involuntarily committed beyond this emergency period. However, in general, if a person is a danger to themselves or others unable to provide for themselves, *and* will continue to be without assistance, then they will meet the criteria for involuntary commitment.

[This chart](http://www.treatmentadvocacycenter.org/storage/documents/State_Standards_Charts_for_Assisted_Treatment_-_Civil_Commitment_Criteria_and_Initiation_Procedures.pdf) has some elaborated and detailed information, state-by-state.